# in vs within usage

Tags: word-usage

If I say I want this job to be done in 5 days, does this sentence have connotation of completing it in the next 5 days. However, what I'd like to express is a expected processing time for this job, I don't want to start the job from now. If this sentence is not suitable for what it should mean, what should I say?

Comment: "I want this job to be completed *5 days from now*."

Answer (score 2):

So basically, you're comparing

> I want the job to be done in 5 days.

And

> I want the job to be done within 5 days.

As per your request, that you don't want to start the job right now, the *more* appropriate sentence would be the latter.
However, the first one too doesn't restrict you that you HAVE to start the job right now